# Manipulating an R dataframe consisting of vector and list columns to 'long' format

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, data-manipulation

Please see the attached dput. I would need to transform the dataframe in question to a form that consists of five columns: Area, Group, Seats, Votes (%) and ShapleyShubik. The number of rows per certain area should be dependent on the number of Groups within that Area. I believe this desired end result is somewhat like of what is referenced as 'long format' of data.

```
structure(list(Area = c("Germany", "France", "Italy", "Spain"
), data = list(structure(list(Group = c("Group1", "Group2 ", 
"Group3 ", "Group4  ", "Group5 ", "Group6  ", "Group7 ", "Group8 ", 
"Group9   "), Seats = c(2L, 13L, 23L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 3L, 1L
), NeededQuota = c(43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L)), structure(list(Group = c("Group2 ", "Group4  ", "Group6  ", 
"Group1", "Group7 ", "Group3 "), Seats = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
9L), NeededQuota = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(
    Group = c("Group4  ", "Group7 ", "Group5 ", "Group2 ", "Group8 ", 
    "Group9   ", "Group1", "Group6  ", "Group3 "), Seats = c(8L, 
    14L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 28L), NeededQuota = c(38L, 
    38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L)), structure(list(
    Group = c("Group6  ", "Group2 ", "Group7 ", "Group3 ", "Group4  ", 
    "Group9   ", "Group5 ", "Group10"), Seats = c(10L, 9L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L), NeededQuota = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L))), models = list(structure(list(Results = structure(c(2, 
0.0235294117647059, 0.0261904761904762, 13, 0.152941176470588, 
0.142857142857143, 23, 0.270588235294118, 0.3, 9, 0.105882352941176, 
0.107142857142857, 11, 0.129411764705882, 0.121428571428571, 
5, 0.0588235294117647, 0.0476190476190476, 18, 0.211764705882353, 
0.214285714285714, 3, 0.0352941176470588, 0.0333333333333333, 
1, 0.0117647058823529, 0.00714285714285714), .Dim = c(3L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Votes", "Votes (%)", "Shapley-Shubik"), c("Group1", "Group2 ", 
    "Group3 ", "Group4  ", "Group5 ", "Group6  ", "Group7 ", 
    "Group8 ", "Group9   "))), Distribution = c(2L, 13L, 23L, 
9L, 11L, 5L, 18L, 3L, 1L), function (object, contr, how.many, 
    ...) 
{
    if (isFALSE(as.logical(Sys.getenv("_R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_")))) 
        object <- as.factor(object)
    if (!nlevels(object)) 
        stop("object not interpretable as a factor")
    if (!missing(contr) && is.name(Xcontr <- substitute(contr))) 
        contr <- switch(as.character(Xcontr), poly = "contr.poly", 
            helmert = "contr.helmert", sum = "contr.sum", treatment = "contr.treatment", 
            SAS = "contr.SAS", contr)
    if (missing(contr)) {
        oc <- getOption("contrasts")
        contr <- if (length(oc) < 2L) 
            if (is.ordered(object)) 
                contr.poly
            else contr.treatment
        else oc[1 + is.ordered(object)]
    }
    if (missing(how.many) && missing(...)) 
        contrasts(object) <- contr
    else {
        if (is.character(contr)) 
            contr <- get(contr, mode = "function")
        if (is.function(contr)) 
            contr <- contr(nlevels(object), ...)
        contrasts(object, how.many) <- contr
    }
    object
}, Method = "PowerIndex", Quota = 43L, Names = c("Group1", "Group2 ", 
"Group3 ", "Group4  ", "Group5 ", "Group6  ", "Group7 ", "Group8 ", 
"Group9   ")), class = "ShapleyShubik"), structure(list(Results = structure(c(5, 
0.185185185185185, 0.166666666666667, 5, 0.185185185185185, 0.166666666666667, 
1, 0.037037037037037, 0, 6, 0.222222222222222, 0.166666666666667, 
1, 0.037037037037037, 0, 9, 0.333333333333333, 0.5), .Dim = c(3L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("Votes", "Votes (%)", "Shapley-Shubik"
), c("Group2 ", "Group4  ", "Group6  ", "Group1", "Group7 ", 
"Group3 "))), Distribution = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 9L), function (object, 
    contr, how.many, ...) 
{
    if (isFALSE(as.logical(Sys.getenv("_R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_")))) 
        object <- as.factor(object)
    if (!nlevels(object)) 
        stop("object not interpretable as a factor")
    if (!missing(contr) && is.name(Xcontr <- substitute(contr))) 
        contr <- switch(as.character(Xcontr), poly = "contr.poly", 
            helmert = "contr.helmert", sum = "contr.sum", treatment = "contr.treatment", 
            SAS = "contr.SAS", contr)
    if (missing(contr)) {
        oc <- getOption("contrasts")
        contr <- if (length(oc) < 2L) 
            if (is.ordered(object)) 
                contr.poly
            else contr.treatment
        else oc[1 + is.ordered(object)]
    }
    if (missing(how.many) && missing(...)) 
        contrasts(object) <- contr
    else {
        if (is.character(contr)) 
            contr <- get(contr, mode = "function")
        if (is.function(contr)) 
            contr <- contr(nlevels(object), ...)
        contrasts(object, how.many) <- contr
    }
    object
}, Method = "PowerIndex", Quota = 14L, Names = c("Group2 ", "Group4  ", 
"Group6  ", "Group1", "Group7 ", "Group3 ")), class = "ShapleyShubik"), 
    structure(list(Results = structure(c(8, 0.106666666666667, 
    0.096031746031746, 14, 0.186666666666667, 0.131746031746032, 
    2, 0.0266666666666667, 0.0198412698412698, 10, 0.133333333333333, 
    0.131746031746032, 2, 0.0266666666666667, 0.0198412698412698, 
    3, 0.04, 0.0198412698412698, 2, 0.0266666666666667, 0.0198412698412698, 
    6, 0.08, 0.0484126984126984, 28, 0.373333333333333, 0.512698412698413
    ), .Dim = c(3L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(c("Votes", "Votes (%)", 
    "Shapley-Shubik"), c("Group4  ", "Group7 ", "Group5 ", "Group2 ", 
    "Group8 ", "Group9   ", "Group1", "Group6  ", "Group3 "))), 
        Distribution = c(8L, 14L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 28L
        ), function (object, contr, how.many, ...) 
        {
            if (isFALSE(as.logical(Sys.getenv("_R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_")))) 
                object <- as.factor(object)
            if (!nlevels(object)) 
                stop("object not interpretable as a factor")
            if (!missing(contr) && is.name(Xcontr <- substitute(contr))) 
                contr <- switch(as.character(Xcontr), poly = "contr.poly", 
                  helmert = "contr.helmert", sum = "contr.sum", 
                  treatment = "contr.treatment", SAS = "contr.SAS", 
                  contr)
            if (missing(contr)) {
                oc <- getOption("contrasts")
                contr <- if (length(oc) < 2L) 
                  if (is.ordered(object)) 
                    contr.poly
                  else contr.treatment
                else oc[1 + is.ordered(object)]
            }
            if (missing(how.many) && missing(...)) 
                contrasts(object) <- contr
            else {
                if (is.character(contr)) 
                  contr <- get(contr, mode = "function")
                if (is.function(contr)) 
                  contr <- contr(nlevels(object), ...)
                contrasts(object, how.many) <- contr
            }
            object
        }, Method = "PowerIndex", Quota = 38L, Names = c("Group4  ", 
        "Group7 ", "Group5 ", "Group2 ", "Group8 ", "Group9   ", 
        "Group1", "Group6  ", "Group3 ")), class = "ShapleyShubik"), 
    structure(list(Results = structure(c(10, 0.32258064516129, 
    0.323809523809524, 9, 0.290322580645161, 0.261904761904762, 
    1, 0.032258064516129, 0.0285714285714286, 3, 0.0967741935483871, 
    0.0952380952380952, 4, 0.129032258064516, 0.157142857142857, 
    1, 0.032258064516129, 0.0285714285714286, 2, 0.0645161290322581, 
    0.0761904761904762, 1, 0.032258064516129, 0.0285714285714286
    ), .Dim = c(3L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("Votes", "Votes (%)", 
    "Shapley-Shubik"), c("Group6  ", "Group2 ", "Group7 ", "Group3 ", 
    "Group4  ", "Group9   ", "Group5 ", "Group10"))), Distribution = c(10L, 
    9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L), function (object, contr, how.many, 
        ...) 
    {
        if (isFALSE(as.logical(Sys.getenv("_R_OPTIONS_STRINGS_AS_FACTORS_")))) 
            object <- as.factor(object)
        if (!nlevels(object)) 
            stop("object not interpretable as a factor")
        if (!missing(contr) && is.name(Xcontr <- substitute(contr))) 
            contr <- switch(as.character(Xcontr), poly = "contr.poly", 
                helmert = "contr.helmert", sum = "contr.sum", 
                treatment = "contr.treatment", SAS = "contr.SAS", 
                contr)
        if (missing(contr)) {
            oc <- getOption("contrasts")
            contr <- if (length(oc) < 2L) 
                if (is.ordered(object)) 
                  contr.poly
                else contr.treatment
            else oc[1 + is.ordered(object)]
        }
        if (missing(how.many) && missing(...)) 
            contrasts(object) <- contr
        else {
            if (is.character(contr)) 
                contr <- get(contr, mode = "function")
            if (is.function(contr)) 
                contr <- contr(nlevels(object), ...)
            contrasts(object, how.many) <- contr
        }
        object
    }, Method = "PowerIndex", Quota = 16L, Names = c("Group6  ", 
    "Group2 ", "Group7 ", "Group3 ", "Group4  ", "Group9   ", 
    "Group5 ", "Group10")), class = "ShapleyShubik"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(Area = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", 
"Spain"), .rows = structure(list(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I initially thought I would have to unnest the structure, and tried

```
ByArea <- outputdata %>%
group_by(Area) %>%
unnest()
```

but it produces an error telling that `Input must be a vector, not a <ShapleyShubik> object`.

EDIT:
The head of the needed output is as such:

```
Area        Group      Seats   Seats(%)        ShapleyShubik
Germany     Group1       2      0.25              0.1234
Germany     Group2       2      0.25              0.1234
Germany     Group3       4      0.50              0.7532
```

Comment: I cant tell the output you need. as to whether `unnest(outputdata,  data)` or even `unnest_wider(outputdata, data)`. Try both and select the one that gives you the output you want

Comment: What is ShapleyShubik? It seems to be the class of one of your columns, but what package does that come from? Maybe you can simplify the sample of data first into something that doesn't require outside packages just to read it properly

Comment: seems you want `unnest(outputdata, data)`

Comment: @camille ShapleyShubik comes from the package GameTheory. I use its command ShapleyShubik() to calculate Shapley-Shubik power indices for the different groups in different countries.

Comment: @Onyambu The output I would need is like that what `unnest(outputdata,data)` returns BUT the two rightmost columns would need to be Votes (%) and ShapleyShubik values for each group. Now it's only "models" with lists in it. I want to somehow assign these values for the groups. I'm editing the needed output to the original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! To get the best answers quickly, it's always best to make your question reproducible. You've got the data here, but not the libraries.

Either way, I think I can help. This is using several of the packages called with `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
showMe <- map_dfr(1:4, # there are four power models in this object
                         # first capture the country for each group
                         # create a vector of repeats the length of the model
                  ~cbind(Area = rep(outputdata$Area[[.x]], 
                                    times = ncol(outputdata$models[[.x]][["Results"]])),
                         # now capture the results
                         t(outputdata$models[[.x]][["Results"]]) %>% 
                           as.data.frame() %>% 
                           # move the groups from row names to a column
                           mutate(Groups = rownames(.), 
                                  .before = 1)))
```

This is what you would see at this point:

```
#                   Area    Groups Votes  Votes (%) Shapley-Shubik
# Group1...1     Germany    Group1     2 0.02352941    0.026190476
# Group2 ...2    Germany   Group2     13 0.15294118    0.142857143
# Group3 ...3    Germany   Group3     23 0.27058824    0.300000000
# Group4  ...4   Germany  Group4       9 0.10588235    0.107142857
# Group5 ...5    Germany   Group5     11 0.12941176    0.121428571
# Group6  ...6   Germany  Group6       5 0.05882353    0.047619048
# Group7 ...7    Germany   Group7     18 0.21176471    0.214285714
# Group8 ...8    Germany   Group8      3 0.03529412    0.033333333
```

Next, remove the row names and trim the whitespace in the `Groups` field.

```
# now remove rownames, then remove whitespace from groups
rownames(showMe) <- NULL
showMe$Groups <- trimws(showMe$Groups)
showMe
#       Area  Groups Votes  Votes (%) Shapley-Shubik
# 1  Germany  Group1     2 0.02352941    0.026190476
# 2  Germany  Group2    13 0.15294118    0.142857143
# 3  Germany  Group3    23 0.27058824    0.300000000
# 4  Germany  Group4     9 0.10588235    0.107142857
# 5  Germany  Group5    11 0.12941176    0.121428571
# 6  Germany  Group6     5 0.05882353    0.047619048
# 7  Germany  Group7    18 0.21176471    0.214285714
```